# Why doesn't $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{U''(x_0)}{m}}$ work for a simple pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator

In a simple pendulum, we know that the angular frequency of small oscillations is $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$. However $\sqrt{\frac{U''(x_0)}{m}}$ gives $\sqrt{gl}$ as the angular frequency.

Let $l$ be the length of the string, let $\theta$ be the angle made by the string with the vertical, and let $m$ be the mass of the bob.

We have $U(\theta) = -mgl\cos\theta$ and $U''(\theta) = mgl\cos\theta$.

$U$ has a minimum at $\theta = 0$.

So the angular frequency of small oscillations is $\sqrt{\frac{U''(0)}{m}} = \sqrt{\frac{mgl}{m}} = \sqrt{gl}$.

What mistake have I made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand where the division by $m$ comes from. This is because you are assuming the kinetic energy to be $K(\dot x) = \frac{m}{2}\dot x^2$. In general, the relevant quantity is $K''(0)$ which corresponds to $m$ in the previous example. This is the kinetic equivalent for the harmonic approximation of potential energy. The correct formula is therefore:
$$
\omega = \sqrt{\frac{U''(x_0)}{K''(0)}}
$$
which has the correct dimensions of inverse of time. In the case of the simple pendulum:
$$
U = -mgl\cos\theta\\
K = \frac{ml^2}{2}\dot\theta^2
$$
so you indeed retrieve:
$$
\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't spot my fairly obvious error before. I was implicitly assuming that the force on the bob was $m\ddot{\theta}$ instead of $ml\ddot{\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=l\theta$, then $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{1}{l}\frac{d}{d\theta}$ so $\frac{d^2 V(x)}{dx^2}=
\frac{1}{l^2}\frac{d^2 V}{d\theta^2}$ so converting derivatives w/r to $x$ to derivatives w/r to $\theta$ yields $\sqrt{g/l}$.